# How would i make this method print multiple random integers, based on the number entered in the parameter

Tags: java, random

At the moment my method only prints a random number.

Heres the method.

```
    public void   printMultiRandom(int howMany){
        Random rand = new Random();
        System.out.println(rand.nextInt(howMany));
```

Comment: You need loop to iterate `howMany` times.

Comment: [The Java Tutorials - The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: Look at the JavaDoc for Random.nextInt.  You are misunderstanding the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public void printMultiRandom(int howMany){
    new Random().ints(howMany)
       .forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have any bounds on what the random number should be, you should use this..

```
public void printMultiRandom(int num){
    while(num-- > 0){
        double gen= 100 * Math.random();
        System.out.println(gen);
    }
}
```

Comment: this gives me an error variable num is already defined in this method

Comment: yes, just had to give it a different name

Comment: But this approach only generates random number between 0 and 100

Comment: Unless you want integer values in which case you can just cast the gen to int before printing